# Eclipse can't find logback-test.xml on my classpath for unit tests

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit, logback

I'm struggling with getting Eclipse to recognize my logging configuration when I quick run tests from within Eclipse (Alt + Shift + X, T), or by running from the Run Configurations.  I really don't care all that much about logging from the tests per se, but really just providing the configuration so that any log statements executed will not fail.

```html
Failed to instantiate [ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext]
Reported exception:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ch.qos.logback.core.util.Loader.getResourceOccurrenceCount(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Ljava/util/Set;
 at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.multiplicityWarning(ContextInitializer.java:160)
 at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.statusOnResourceSearch(ContextInitializer.java:183)
 at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.getResource(ContextInitializer.java:141)
 at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.findURLOfDefaultConfigurationFile(ContextInitializer.java:130)
 at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:148)
 at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:85)
 at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
 at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:144)
 at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:123)
 at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:337)
 at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:287)
 at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:309)
```

I have logback-test.xml in src/test/resources, and have configured that as a source folder with an output of target/test-classes.

[image]
[image]

I even took at shot at editing the Classpath of the Run Configuration for JUnit for my project, and added the test-classes folder there, and it didn't help.

[image]

Is there something simple that I'm missing?  I don't seem to recall having this issue in the past with other projects.

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError usually means mismatched classes or jar files.

Comment: @nitind This was the problem. I checked my pom.xml and resolved the version conflict. Thanks.

Comment: Same for me for a regular java application (without eclipse). the problem is a conflict version between logback-core and logback-classic

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I checked my pom.xml, and logback-classic didn't have a specified version, and logback-core did. I set a property for the version and set them both to be the same.